# Sharing one encoder/pattern among multiple Appenders in Logback

Tags: java, logging, jakarta-ee, logback

This is my first foray into the world of LogBack, however I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation where I could define an encoder/pattern once and share it among multiple appenders. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For anyone interested I did find this little jewel from [Chapter 4](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) of LogBack's documentation: ***"Each layout/encoder is associated with one and only one appender, referred to as the owning appender."*** which to me reads as though it's not possible for Appenders to share a single Encoder instance.

Comment: I've been programmatically creating appenders, encoders and layouts. I think the above is true: when I tried to share the encoders amongst appenders, I'd just end up having only one appender active (presumably because the encoder ended up only being attached to the last one I added it to).

Comment: Also this from the Configuration section: "Note that each appender has its own encoder. Encoders are usually not designed to be shared by multiple appenders. The same is true for layouts. As such, logback configuration files do not provide any syntactical means for sharing encoders or layouts."

Answer (score 58):

Patterns are reusable with [variable substitution](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution).

```
<configuration>

    <property name="defaultPattern"
        value="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${defaultPattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This does not work with more complex pattern like `%replace(%replace([%X{req.method} %X{req.requestURI} %X{req.queryString}] ){'\s+',' '}){'\[\s\]\s', ''}`

Comment: The solution is to double back slashes.